# variable using for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I render the for loop using variable count. Please check this example

I have 5 variable like this:

```
var reactionWeightage5 = 30;
var reactionWeightage4 = 06;
var reactionWeightage3 = 70;
var reactionWeightage2 = 80;
var reactionWeightage1 = 10;
```

i need render like this

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    var test = reactionWeightage[i];
    etc .....
}
```

i am getting the following error :

> "reactionWeightage is not defined"

Can anyone help for this?

Comment: Why do you have 5 separate variables instead of an array with 5 entries?

Comment: If you really want to (I'd go for the Array option though) you could do something like `this['reactionWeightage' + i]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest way is to just create the array like so:

```
var reactionWeightage = [30, 06, 70, 80, 10];
```

Iterate

```
for (var i = 0; i < reactionWeightage.length; i++) {
     console.log(reactionWeightage[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

reactionWeight is not an array. You need to use arrays if you use the [] operator.

Try creating something like this:

```
var mycars = new Array();
mycars[0] = "Saab";
mycars[1] = "Volvo";
mycars[2] = "BMW";
```

then you can access it like this:

`alert(mycars[2]); //will alert BMW`

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_array.asp

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using five variables, use for example a dictionary/object:

```
var reactionWeightage = {
    5: 30,
    4: 06,
    3: 70,
    2: 80,
    1: 10
};

for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    var test = reactionWeightage[i];
    etc .....
}
```

However to answer the question completely here's an example how to achieve what you want (only for academic purposes, **do not use it in real code**):

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    var test = eval('reactionWeightage'+i);
    etc .....
}
```

Comment: dictionary? are you ok?

Comment: @Trickster: It's a valid term :-)

Comment: @Trickster - are you ok?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define reactionWeightage as an array, not declare 5 separate variables. Minimally fixing what you've got already:

```
var reactionWeightage = new Array();
reactionWeightage[5] = 30;
reactionWeightage[4] = 06;
reactionWeightage[3] = 70;
reactionWeightage[2] = 80;
reactionWeightage[1] = 10;
```